# How to get the url images of twitter api and put in googlesheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, twitter, twitter-api-v2

my code works in appscript with the GET call with fetch, then fetch gives me an array with different data nested, my code destructuring the data to get what I need, and put in a new array, each array with the data of each tweet, then this new array is pushed in the mainArray and so on with each tweet, after that, I use the SetValues to put each arrayData in each row and each data separate with columns in a doc of Google sheets

The code work for the link, tweet, username, date, like, comment and share.
But I want to add the URL or preview_url in a new column if the tweet has an image o video, or if have a media_key, if the tweet has multiple images I only want the first one.

This is the code I use to manage all the data from the GET of Fetch

```
if(huboResultados){
const values = () => {
    const {data, includes} = datos
    let arrayData = [] 
    let arrayMetricas = []

    data.map(item => {
        const { author_id, id, text, created_at, public_metrics} = item 
        const {retweet_count, reply_count, like_count} = public_metrics;
        const totalinteracciones = retweet_count + reply_count + like_count 
        const idTweet = id;

        Logger.log(public_metrics)

        includes.users.map(user => {
            const { id, name, username} = user

            if(author_id === id){
                arrayData = ["twitter.com/anyuser/status/" + idTweet, text, username, created_at, like_count, reply_count, retweet_count, totalinteracciones]
            }
            return arrayData
        })
        
        Logger.log(mainArray)
        return mainArray.push(arrayData)
    })   
}


values()

var totaltweets = mainArray.length

Logger.log(query)
Logger.log(totaltweets)
Logger.log (activesheet.getLastRow())
activesheet.getRange("B10:I"+ activesheet.getLastRow()).clearContent()
activesheet.getRange(10,2,totaltweets, mainArray[0].length).setValues(mainArray);
}
}
```

And this is an example of the type of data I get from Fetch:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "text": "RT @PabloDa65125285: Oye #TataMartino porque No te quieren en La Selección:\n#FueraTata #SeleccionMexicana #Qatar2022 #Colombia #Chiringuito…",
            "public_metrics": {
                "retweet_count": 4,
                "reply_count": 0,
                "like_count": 0,
                "quote_count": 0
            },
            "created_at": "2022-09-28T14:59:33.000Z",
            "author_id": "1297299916654608389",
            "id": "1575138146433499138"
        },
        {
            "attachments": {
                "media_keys": [
                    "7_1575137009743659009"
                ]
            },
            "text": "@miseleccionmx Ya tiene chamba asegurada el Tata en la sección de \"Quién es quien en las mentiras\" \n#QuienEsQuienEnLasMentiras \n#AMLOBurlaMundial \n#SeleccionMexicana \n#MasAccionMasDiversion https://  t.co/73jOxVjydh",
            "public_metrics": {
                "retweet_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 0,
                "like_count": 0,
                "quote_count": 0
            },
            "created_at": "2022-09-28T14:55:07.000Z",
            "author_id": "974663527104356352",
            "id": "1575137031843373063"
        },
        }
     ],
    "includes": {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "1297299916654608389",
                "name": "Juanma76",
                "username": "Juanma7611"
            },
            {
                "id": "974663527104356352",
                "name": "Ro2 ",
                "username": "ro2var"
            },
        ],
        "media": [
            {
                "media_key": "7_1575137009743659009",
                "preview_image_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/1575137009743659009/pu/img/qluOCv0Uw_u2J_SG.jpg",
                "type": "video"
            },
            {
            "media_key": "3_1575014644439212032",
            "type": "photo",
            "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FduTeW3WYAAEm7W.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta": {
        "newest_id": "1575138146433499138",
        "oldest_id": "1575088073242574849",
        "result_count": 10,
        "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fpzblrml2r91pb8ibeaxwgyo2ee8ot"
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading, and sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to get the `media` URLs inside of `includes`. Please try the following for the first part of your code:

```
var mainArray = [];

const values = () => {
    const {data, includes} = datos;
    let arrayData = [] ;
    let arrayMetricas = [];

    var mapImages = {};

    for (var i=0;i<includes.media.length;i++){
        if (includes.media[i].preview_image_url != undefined ){
            mapImages[includes.media[i].media_key] = {"preview_url": includes.media[i].preview_image_url}
        }
        if (includes.media[i].url != undefined ){
            mapImages[includes.media[i].media_key]  = {"url":includes.media[i].url}
        }
    }

    data.map(item => {
        const { author_id, id, text, created_at, public_metrics} = item 
        const {retweet_count, reply_count, like_count} = public_metrics;
        const totalinteracciones = retweet_count + reply_count + like_count 
        const idTweet = id;
        var preview_url = ""
        var url = ""
        if (item.attachments != undefined){
          for (var i=0;i<item.attachments.media_keys.length;i++){
            if (mapImages[item.attachments.media_keys[i]] != undefined){
              if(mapImages[item.attachments.media_keys[i]].url != undefined){
                url = mapImages[item.attachments.media_keys[i]].url
              }
              else if (mapImages[item.attachments.media_keys[i]].preview_url != undefined){
                preview_url = mapImages[item.attachments.media_keys[i]].preview_url
              }
            }
          }
        }

        Logger.log(public_metrics)

        includes.users.map(user => {
            const { id, name, username} = user

            if(author_id === id){
                arrayData = ["twitter.com/anyuser/status/" + idTweet, text, username, created_at, like_count, reply_count, retweet_count, totalinteracciones, url, preview_url]
            }
            return arrayData
        })


        return mainArray.push(arrayData)
    })   
}

values()
```

**Edit**: included mapImages to gather to mappings of media_keys that will need to be looked up in each of the tweets

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help and the time, but the code doesn´t work as I need, also is true that I have not explained myself very well, sorry for that  I edit my post I hope that clarified what I want,  your code takes the first image, or preview_url, it finds and prints it in each row of the results in separate columns even if the tweet doesn´t have an image or video.

Comment: No worries - I have edited the answer to include the media_keys mappings to find the matching attachments, thanks for clarifying